# How to identify vb.net codes,aspx code

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Hi I'm new to Visual Studio.NET.I saw a tutorial but I can't see any good relevant with the tutorial.I know it is very baisc for .NET guys to identify this code.I just want to learn this stuff.
I'm currently working(helping) on a project they said that it is a .NET project.
But I'm confused with C#.net,asp.net,vb.net
Here is the some of the snippets from the file tasksconfig.aspx.

I'm confused because I saw **Language="vb"** but still I saw asp tags.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/AuthenticatedMaster.master" CodeBehind="TasksConfig.aspx.vb" Inherits="www.TasksConfig" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="cc" TagName="ErrorNotify" Src="~/controls/ErrorNotification.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="cc" TagName="TaskProp" Src="~/controls/TaskPropertiesDialog.ascx" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="www" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="titleContent" runat="server">
    <table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' style='width:100%;'>
    <tr>
        <td align='left'>
            <b class='page-header-text'>Tasks</b>
        </td>
        <td align='right'>
            <cc:ErrorNotify runat='server' ID='errNotif' />
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

</asp:Content>
```

[image: Soluton Explorer:Filenames.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By all appearances this is an ASP .NET project using VB for the code behind files.